# Is there a neater alternative to `except: pass`?

Tags: python, exception, coding-style

I had a function that returned a random member of several groups in order of preference. It went something like this:

```
def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    "I'd rather have a foo than a bar."

    if there_are_foos():
        return get_random_foo()

    if there_are_bars():
        return get_random_bar()

    raise IndexError, "No foos, no bars"
```

However, the first thing `get_random_foo` does is verify there are foos and raise an `IndexError` if not, so `there_are_foos` is redundant. Moreover, a database is involved and using separate functions creates a concurrency issue. Accordingly, I rewrote it something like this:

```
def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    "Still prefer foos."

    try:
        return get_random_foo()
    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        return get_random_bar()
    except IndexError:
        pass

    raise IndexError, "No foos, no bars"
```

But I find this much less readable, and as I've never had reason to use `pass` before it feels instictively wrong.

Is there a neater efficient pattern, or should I learn to accept `pass`?

Note: I'd like to avoid any nesting since other types may be added later.

---

**Edit**

Thanks everyone who said that `pass` is fine - that's reassuring!

Also thanks to those who suggested replacing the exception with a return value of `None`. I can see how this is a useful pattern, but I would argue it's semantically wrong in this situation: the functions have been asked to perform an impossible task so they should raise an exception. I prefer to follow the behaviour of the `random` module (eg. `random.choice([])`).

Comment: The use in `except` statements is probably the most common use of `pass` in Python. So I would get used to it.

Comment: "But I find this much less readable ... it feels instictively wrong" — think of it as a cultural issue. It seems strange now, but it's the cleanest way to use the language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is exactly how I would write it. It's simple and it makes sense. I see no problem with the `pass` statements.

If you want to reduce the repetition and you anticipate adding future types, you could roll this up into a loop. Then you could change the `pass` to a functionally-equivalent `continue` statement, if that's more pleasing to your eyes:

```
for getter in (get_random_foo, get_random_bar):
    try:
        return getter()
    except IndexError:
        continue  # Ignore the exception and try the next type.

raise IndexError, "No foos, no bars"
```

Answer (score 6):

Using try, except, pass is acceptable, but there is a cleaner way to write this using [`contextlib.suppress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) available for python 3.4+.

```
from contextlib import suppress

def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    "Still prefer foos."

    with suppress(IndexError):
        return get_random_foo()

    with suppress(IndexError):
        return get_random_bar()

    raise IndexError("No foos, no bars")
```

Answer (score 2):

`pass` is fine (there's a *reason* it's in the language!-), but a pass-free alternative just takes a bit more nesting:

```
try: return get_random_foo()
except IndexError:
    try: return get_random_bar()
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError "no foos, no bars"
```

Python's Zen (`import this` from the interactive interpreter prompt) says "flat is better than nested", but nesting is *also* in the language, for you to use when you decide (presumably being enlightened) that you can do better than that wise koan!-)  (As in, "if you meet the Buddha on the road"...).

Answer (score 2):

It looks a little weird to me that `get_random_foo()` is raising an IndexError when it doesn't take an index as a param (but it might make more sense in context). Why not have `get_random_foo()`, or a wrapper, catch the error and return None instead?

```
def get_random_foo_wrapper():
    try:
        return get_random_foo()
    except IndexError:
        return None

def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    "I'd rather have a foo than a bar."

    return get_random_foo_wrapper() or get_random_bar_wrapper() or None
```

**Edit**: I should mention that if foo & bar are objects that may evaluate to False (0 or '' say) then the `or` comparison will skip over them which is BAD

Comment: I took my cue from the random module - try running `random.choice([])`. Interesting solution though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's just those two, could always just...

```
try:
    return get_random_foo()
except IndexError:
    try:
        return get_random_bar()
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError, "No foos, no bars"
```

If it's more than two, what you have written seems perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Peter Gibson's suggestion, you could create a generic wrapper function that swallows a given exception. And then you could write a function that *returns* such a generic wrapper for a provided exception. Or heck, for a provided *list* of exceptions.

```
def maketrap(*exceptions):
    def trap(func, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions:
            return None
    return trap

def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    mytrap = maketrap(IndexError)
    return mytrap(get_random_foo) or mytrap(get_random_bar) or None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need the exception message (just the type):

```
def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    try:
        return get_random_foo()
    except IndexError:
        return get_random_bar()    # if failing at this point,
                                   # the whole function will raise IndexError
```

Comment: I think I would prefer to raise the error explicitly from `get_random_foo_or_bar` rather than relying on the error happening to be the same and needing a comment. Also that allows me to return an appropriate exception message from `get_random_foo_or_bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that get_random_foo/bar() raise an IndexError if it's unable to succeed?

If they returned None, you could do:

```
def get_random_foo_or_bar():
    return get_random_foo() or get_random_bar()
```