# Continue running python code even if error occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

is it possible to continue excecution of code even after an error occurs?

Suppose I have code named `app.py` which contains following code -

```
def call(temp):
    call=temp+1
    t=fast+1
    if temp==11:
        c=22/3
    else:
        c=1
    return 5
```

Here `fast` is not defined but i want still want the code to excecute even after this error occurs.

I looked into the internet and found the found the `pass` trick but it isnt working in my case?

```
import app
def test_call():
    try:
        app.call(11)
    except Exception:
        pass
test_call()
```

In my case , the code is executed upto the `fast` line only. Is there any way to continue the excecution?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example?  What is the point of having the code continue if `t` hasn't been assigned a value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it in the `call` function.

```
def call(temp):
    call=temp+1
    try:
        t=fast+1
    except Exception:
        pass
    if temp==11:
        c=22/3
    else:
        c=1
    return 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some informations you may use, if you click 'Mark all unresolved attributes of..' option, it would solve your problem. [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/resolving-references.html)

Answer (score -2):

use `try-except` condition in python

```
try:
   #any calculations
except:
   pass
```

The `pass` in `except` just ignores any error that caused the program to catch exception 
Also if this isn't working refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723302/is-there-a-neater-alternative-to-except-pass)